# Impossible to add "flexipage:availableForRecordHome" on a component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, interface

I'm trying to create a new lightning component that should be displayed on a record page. However the error I'm getting this error when I'm adding the interface

```
Deployment Failed: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION - Invalid definition for null:Function: null: Source
```

I don't really understand where it's coming from as that interface is working perfectly on other components

Comment: Does the problem `aura:component` `extends` another component?

Comment: No it doesn't extends another component.

Comment: please share your code